# System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The client disconnected. ---> System.Web.UI.ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

Recently we have migrated our website from windows 2003 server to Windows 2008 server. This website is load balanced. We are experiencing the intermittent Invalid view state errors.

In the both servers web.conifg has Machine key (static) configured. Also, same machine key was used in Machine.Config file as well. But still the invalid view state errors are not resolved.

Please let me know how to fix the below invalid view state errors.

System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' was thrown. ---> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The client disconnected. ---> System.Web.UI.ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Sounds like the page is served from one server and posted back to a different server. ]

Comment: any thoughts on how to resolve this error... I think user will not face any issue with this error right?